# variables in remote nested server via ssh

Tags: bash, shell, variables, ssh, sh

Trying to set and access some variables on a remote server
the script will execute on a local server, it will login to remote-server1 and then login again to another second remote server remote-server2
I can successfully set and access variables in both local and remote-server1 without any issues, but having problem doing the same on remote-server2

```
local1=$(echo "local-srv"); echo "${local1}"
output=$(sshpass -p "${PSSWD}" ssh -t -q -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@$mgmtIP "bash -s" <<EOF
remote1=\$(echo "remote-srv1"); echo "\${remote1}"
ssh -t -q -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no "${targetCompute}" "bash -s" <<EOF2
remote2=\$(echo "remote-srv2"); echo "\${remote2}"
EOF2
EOF
)
```

**Here is my output**

```
local-srv
remote-srv1
```

as you can see *remote-srv2* is missing

----- UPDATE ---

please note that  `$(echo "text")`  is just for simplicity but a complex command will be executed here and the output set to a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two nested `ssh` commands with nested here-documents, and to delay interpretation of the `$` expressions in the inner one, you need more escapes. To see the problem, you can replace the `ssh` command with `cat` to see what would be sent to the remote computer. Here's an example, using your original code (and some modified variable definitions); note that the `$` and `>` are prompts from my shell.

```
$ targetCompute=remote-server2
$ local1="local-srv"; echo "${local1}"
local-srv
$ cat <<EOF
> remote1=\$(echo "remote-srv1"); echo "\${remote1}"
> ssh -t -q -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no "${targetCompute}" "bash -s" <<EOF2
> remote2=\$(echo "remote-srv2"); echo "\${remote2}"
> EOF2
> EOF
remote1=$(echo "remote-srv1"); echo "${remote1}"
ssh -t -q -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no "remote-server2" "bash -s" <<EOF2
remote2=$(echo "remote-srv2"); echo "${remote2}"
EOF2
```

Notice that the lines relating to `remote1` and `remote2` have both had their escapes removed, so they're both going to have their `$` expressions expanded on remote-srv1. That's what you want for the `remote1` line, but to delay interpretation of the `remote2` line you have to add another escape... and that escape itself needs to be escaped, so there'll actually be [three escapes](https://xkcd.com/1638/) before each `$`:

```
$ cat <<EOF
> remote1=\$(echo "remote-srv1"); echo "\${remote1}"
> ssh -t -q -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no "${targetCompute}" "bash -s" <<EOF2
> remote2=\\\$(echo "remote-srv2"); echo "\\\${remote2}"
> EOF2
> EOF
remote1=$(echo "remote-srv1"); echo "${remote1}"
ssh -t -q -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no "remote-server2" "bash -s" <<EOF2
remote2=\$(echo "remote-srv2"); echo "\${remote2}"
EOF2
```

So `\\\$(echo "remote-srv2")` and `"\\\${remote2}"` in the local here-document become `\$(echo "remote-srv2")` and `"\${remote2}"` in the here-document on remote-srv1, and then the command actually gets executed and the variable expanded on remote-srv2.

Comment: thanks for your answer, $(echo "remote-srv2") is just for simplicity, this will be executing a complex command and the output stored in a variable. your anser is correct but the first part is not necessary, updated to question too to reflect this

Comment: @electricalbah Ah, that makes sense; I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to escape by `///`

Thanks to the answer given by @Goron Davisson

```
local1=$(echo "local-srv"); echo "${local1}"
output=$(sshpass -p "${PSSWD}" ssh -t -q -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@$mgmtIP "bash -s" <<EOF
remote1=\$(echo "remote-srv1"); echo "\${remote1}"
ssh -t -q -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no "${targetCompute}" "bash -s" <<EOF2
remote2=\\\$(echo "remote-srv2"); echo "\\\${remote2}"
EOF2
EOF
)
```

**Output**

```
local-srv
remote-srv1
remote-srv2
```